# Firestore get all document of a sub collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a function where it generate report every 2 hours. For now the schedule I fixed it for testing purposes. I am currently facing the problem of getting all of the data of `transactions` from `shops` in order to calculate and generate a record in `reports` collection. The below code return error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

```
exports.generateReport = functions.pubsub.schedule('25 14 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    const shopSnapshot = await db.collection("shops").get();
    const shopDoc = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    console.log(shopDoc);

    for(var i=0; i<shopDoc.length; i++){
        console.log(shopDoc[i].id);
        if(shopDoc[i].id !== "" || shopDoc[i].id !== null){
            console.log("Enter if:"+shopDoc[i].id);
            let transactionSnapshot = db.collection("shops").doc(shopDoc[i].id).collection("transactions").get();
            let transactionDoc = transactionSnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
            console.log(transactionDoc);
        }
    }
```

[image: The image of firestore]

Comment: So you want to get the data under all subcollections, `points`, `reports`, `subscribers` and `transactions`?

Comment: I want to get data of all ```transactions```

Comment: So those are documents not subcollections, right?

Comment: Ya sorry I made a mistake

Comment: You are not `await`ing the result of `get` in your loop, therefore, `transactionSnapshot` is not what you think it is!

Comment: But if I put ```await``` for the ```get``` in the loop, it will prompt error of ```unexpected await inside a loop```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Promise.all()` to wait that **all** the asynchronous `get()` operations are completed before you proceed.

You could do as follows:

```
exports.generateReport = functions.pubsub.schedule('25 14 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    const shopSnapshot = await db.collection("shops").get();
    const shopDoc = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    console.log(shopDoc);

    const promises = [];
 
    for(var i=0; i<shopDoc.length; i++){
        console.log(shopDoc[i].id);

        if(shopDoc[i].id !== "" || shopDoc[i].id !== null){
            promises.push(db.collection("shops").doc(shopDoc[i].id).collection("transactions").get());
        }
    }

    const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);
    // snapshotArrays contains an array of arrays of QueryDocumentSnapshots 

    snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray => {
        snapArray.forEach(snap => {
             // Proceed here with the snap (DocumentSnapshot)
             //E.g. sum up the amount or points values
           }))
        })
    }); 
    //Or call map on snapshotArrays.docs 
  
    // ....
    return null;  // or return the promise returned by an asynchronous method
```

---

Note that you may need to do this calculation in a [`Transaction`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html), within your Cloud Function, to avoid a new transaction document is added while you are calculating.

The Admin SDK for Node.js includes the [`getAll()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#getAll) method, which "retrieves **multiple documents** from Firestore and holds a pessimistic lock on all returned documents."

Answer (score 1):

`get()` is asynchronous and it returns a `Promise<DocumentSnapshot>`, which means you can use `then()` to be able to get the data from the `Promise`, for example:

```
 let transactionSnapshot = db.collection("shops").doc(shopDoc[i].id).collection("transactions").get().then((doc) => {
 let transactionDoc = transactionSnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
 console.log(transactionDoc);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get

Comment: However, this doesn't guarantee that all the work will get completed, because the entire callback function doesn't return a promise that resolves when all the work is complete.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions